# SQL Statement to check first character for first and last name from textbox

Tags: sql, full-text-search, sql-like

I am trying to write a SQL statement or statements that will retrieve the account information based on a textbox entry of a person’s initials (last, first).   The following statement works when you enter only one letter, but not too.

```
'variable
Dim strDataSource As String
Dim connStr As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source = Chapter4.mdb"

strDataSource = "SELECT CustID, LastName, FirstName " & _
       "FROM tblCustomers " & _
       "WHERE UCase(TRIM(LastName)) LIKE '" & UCase(Me.txtCustID.Text) & "%'" 

Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim dataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strDataSource, connStr)

dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
dataAdapter.Dispose()

Me.dgvDisplay.DataSource = dt
```

I cannot figure out how to add the FirstName to the search.
Thanks

Comment: add or condition for firstname too similar to lastname in the where clause

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the names of your fields in your form, but what Rajesh is suggesting is something similar to the following.  If you only want the first OR the last name to match, then use OR instead of AND in the WHERE clause.

```
strDataSource = "SELECT CustID, LastName, FirstName " & _
       "FROM tblCustomers " & _
       "WHERE UCase(TRIM(LastName)) LIKE '" & UCase(Me.txtCustID.Text) & "%'" _
        AND UCase(TRIM(FirstName)) LIKE '" & UCase(Me.txtFirstName.Text)
```

Comment: I can still Only put 1 Character to be able to complete a search.   Both the first and last initial is being entered into 1 text box.  If I enter the 2nd character in said no records found.

Comment: Okay, so maybe I misunderstood what you need to have happen.  Are you saying you have only one text entry box on your form and you are trying to split the string into two separate search criteria?  If you do that you have to split the string into the two separate strings using something like SUBSTRING() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx.  This could a problem design though.  What happens if the user enters 3 characters or more?  Can you use 2 text boxes?

Answer (score 0):

You should mention this is in VB.

**Assumptions:**

The first character they enter in is for Last Name.

The second character they enter in is for First Name.

```
strDataSource = "SELECT CustID, LastName, FirstName " & _
   "FROM tblCustomers " & _
   "WHERE UCase(TRIM(LastName)) LIKE '" & UCase(Me.txtCustID.Text(0)) & "%'"
IF Me.txtCustID.Text.Length > 1 THEN
    strDataSource += " AND UCase(TRIM(FirstName)) LIKE '" &_
    UCase(Me.txtCustID.Text(1)) & "%'"
END IF
```